# Open command prompt on remote windows server

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, windows-server

I would like to clarify something, when I say open cmd, I mean literally/physically open the cmd on the windows server. For example, if I use RDP to connect to the server then I can see the cmd open on the display.

I have used ssh to connect to a remote server then executed a script but it only executes this script in the background, I have not found a way to literally display the cmd running the script. I am trying to start my selenium grid remotely but IE instance cannot start the test unless the command prompt running the selenium node is displayed. I have found chrome can handle the situation fine, it will run the test on a hidden display. However, IE cannot do the same.

Comment: Is this yoour answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797419/selenium-grid-launching-remote-ie-browser-as-run-as-administrator

Comment: I don't believe so.